# How can I write a Linux bash script that tells me which computers are ON in my LAN?

Tags: linux, bash, ping

How can I write a Linux Bash script that tells me which computers are ON in my LAN?

It would help if I could give it a range of IP addresses as input.

Comment: It could be a good idea to use Nagios http://www.nagios.org/ instead of running script every time, but if you are in hurry it's very usefull 

(+1)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I would suggest using nmap's ping-scan flag,

```
$ nmap -sn 192.168.1.60-70

Starting Nmap 4.11 ( http://www.insecure.org/nmap/ ) at 2009-04-09 20:13 BST
Host machine1.home (192.168.1.64) appears to be up.
Host machine2.home (192.168.1.65) appears to be up.
Nmap finished: 11 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 0.235 seconds
```

That said, if you want to write it yourself (which is fair enough), this is how I would do it:

```
for ip in 192.168.1.{1..10}; do ping -c 1 -t 1 $ip > /dev/null && echo "${ip} is up"; done
```

..and an explanation of each bit of the above command:

### Generating list of IP addresses

You can use the `{1..10}` syntax to generate a list of numbers, for example..

```
$ echo {1..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

(it's also useful for things like `mkdir {dir1,dir2}/{sub1,sub2}` - which makes `dir1` and `dir2`, each containing `sub1` and `sub2`)

So, to generate a list of IP's, we'd do something like

```
$ echo 192.168.1.{1..10}
192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 [...] 192.168.1.10
```

### Loops

To loop over something in bash, you use `for`:

```
$ for thingy in 1 2 3; do echo $thingy; done
1
2
3
```

### Pinging

Next, to ping.. The ping command varies a bit with different operating-systems, different distributions/versions (I'm using OS X currently)

By default (again, on the OS X version of `ping`) it will ping until interrupted, which isn't going to work for this, so `ping -c 1` will only try sending one packet, which should be enough to determine if a machine is up.

Another problem is the timeout value, which seems to be 11 seconds on this version of ping.. It's changed using the `-t` flag. One second should be enough to see if a machine on the local network is alive or not.

So, the ping command we'll use is..

```
$ ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1): 56 data bytes

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

### Checking ping result

Next, we need to know if the machine replied or not..

We can use the `&&` operator to run a command if the first succeeds, for example:

```
$ echo && echo "It works"

It works
$ nonexistantcommand && echo "This should not echo"
-bash: nonexistantcommand: command not found
```

Good, so we can do..

ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.1.1 && echo "192.168.1.1 is up!"

The other way would be to use the exit code from ping.. The ping command will exit with exit-code 0 (success) if it worked, and a non-zero code if it failed. In bash you get the last commands exit code with the variable `$?`

So, to check if the command worked, we'd do..

```
ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.1.1;
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "192.168.1.1 is up";
else 
    echo "ip is down";
fi
```

### Hiding ping output

Last thing, we don't need to see the ping output, so we can redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null` with the `>` redirection, for example:

```
$ ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.1.1 > /dev/null && echo "IP is up"
IP is up
```

And to redirect `stderr` (to discard the `ping: sendto: Host is down` messages), you use `2>` - for example:

```
$ errorcausingcommand
-bash: errorcausingcommand: command not found
$ errorcausingcommand 2> /dev/null
$
```

### The script

So, to combine all that..

```
for ip in 192.168.1.{1..10}; do  # for loop and the {} operator
    ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.1.1 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null  # ping and discard output
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then  # check the exit code
        echo "${ip} is up" # display the output
        # you could send this to a log file by using the >>pinglog.txt redirect
    else
        echo "${ip} is down"
    fi
done
```

Or, using the `&&` method, in a one-liner:

```
for ip in 192.168.1.{1..10}; do ping -c 1 -t 1 $ip > /dev/null && echo "${ip} is up"; done
```

### Problem

It's slow.. Each ping command takes about 1 second (since we set the -t timeout flag to 1 second). It can only run one ping command at a time.. The obvious way around this is to use threads, so you can run concurrent commands, but that's beyond what you should use bash for..

["Python threads - a first example"](http://www.wellho.net/solutions/python-python-threads-a-first-example.html) explains how to use the Python threading module to write a multi-threaded ping'er.. Although at that point, I would once again suggest using `nmap -sn`..

Comment: Is there a way to create and initiate threads in BASH?
This probably could be done in ruby/python as a script just opening an  Network connection, but could the same ability to create multiple threads can be done in BASH?

Comment: You could run the process in the background the command by doing `mycmd &`, but that's not really threading, and could become quite complicated if you need the output of several commands.. It would be much simpler to just use Python/Ruby/etc..

Comment: `for ip in 192.168.1.{1..10}; do ping -c 1 -t 1 $ip > /dev/null && echo "${ip} is up" & done ; wait`

Comment: update: `nmap -sP` is now deprecated. `nmap -sn` is the current option to obtain the same output.

Comment: Why not make it paralell `for ip in 192.168.23.{1..254}; do (ping -c 1 -t 1 $ip > /dev/null && echo ">>> ${ip} is up"; ) & done`

Comment: Just wanted to appreciate the detailing of the commands. The Bash syntax isn't verbose like other languages and makes it tough for beginners.

Comment: `if ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.1.1 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null ; then do_this; else do_that; fi` so you don't have to test the value of  `$?`, just my two cents.

Answer (score 14):

In the real world, you could use **[nmap](http://nmap.org/)** to get what you want.

```
nmap -sn 10.1.1.1-255
```

This will ping all the addresses in the range 10.1.1.1 to 10.1.1.255 and let you know which ones answer.

Of course, if you in fact want to do this as a bash exercise, you could run ping for each address and parse the output, but that's a whole other story.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming my network is 10.10.0.0/24, if i run a ping on the broadcast address like

```
ping -b 10.10.0.255
```

I'll get an answer from all computers on this network that did not block their ICMP ping port.

```
64 bytes from 10.10.0.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.000 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.0.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.000 ms 
64 bytes from 10.10.0.71: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.000 ms
```

So you just have to extract the 4th column, with awk for example:

```
ping -b 10.10.0.255 | grep 'bytes from' | awk '{ print $4 }'

10.10.0.12:
10.10.0.6:
10.10.0.71:
10.10.0.95:
```

Well, you will get duplicate, and you may need to remove the ':'.

EDIT from comments :
the -c option limits the number of pings
since the script will end, we can also limit ourself on unique IPs

```
ping -c 5 -b 10.10.0.255 | grep 'bytes from' | awk '{ print $4 }' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: ping -b 10.10.0.255 | awk '{ print $4 }' | sort | uniq will remove the duplicates

Comment: @Ben: You should add the -c option in the call to ping, because otherwise it won't terminate.

Comment: the -b option is not present for all pings. for example it is OK on my OpenSuse, but not on my Mac, you still can try without this option

Answer (score 8):

There is also [fping](http://fping.sourceforge.net/):

```
fping -g 192.168.1.0/24
```

or:

```
fping -g 192.168.1.0 192.168.1.255
```

or show only hosts that are alive:

```
fping -ag 192.168.1.0/24
```

It pings hosts in parallel so the scan is very fast. I don't know a distribution which includes `fping` in its default installation but in most distributions you can get it through the package manager.

Answer (score 2):

Also using the "ping the broadcast address" method pointed out by chburd, this pipe should do the trick for you:

```
ping -c 5 -b 10.11.255.255 | sed -n 's/.* \([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' | sort | uniq
```

Of course, you'd have to change the broadcast address to that of your network.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's an alternate

```
     #!/bin/bash
     nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 > /dev/null 2>&1 && arp -an | grep -v incomplete | awk '{print$2}' | sed -e s,\(,, | sed -e s,\),,
```

Comment: You can combine <<grep -v incomplete | awk '{print$2}'>> into just <<awk '!/incomplete/{print$2}'>>

Answer (score 1):

If you're limiting yourself to only having the last octet changing, this script should do it. It should be fairly obvious how to extend it from one to multiple octets.

```
#! /bin/bash
BASE=$1
START=$2
END=$3

counter=$START

while [ $counter -le $END ]
do
  ip=$BASE.$counter
  if ping -qc 2 $ip
  then
    echo "$ip responds"
  fi
  counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

- [`ip neighbor`](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-neighbor.html)
- [`arp -a`](http://linux-ip.net/html/ether-arp.html#ether-arp-cache)
- [Arpwatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpwatch)

Comment: "ip neighbor" and "arp -a" won't show machines with which you have not communicated for a while (or at all)

Answer (score 1):

As other posters pointed out, `nmap` is the way to go, but here's how to do the equivalent of a ping scan in bash.  I wouldn't use the broadcast ping, as a lot of systems are configured not to respond to broadcast ICMP nowadays.

```
for i in $(seq 1 254); do
    host="192.168.100.$i"
    ping -c 1 -W 1 $host &> /dev/null
    echo -n "Host $host is "
    test $? -eq 0 && echo "up" || echo "down"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Get the ip address for the range
ip=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d"." -f1,2,3)

# ping test and list the hosts and echo the info

for range in $ip ; do  [ $? -eq 0 ] && ping -c 1 -w 1 $range > /dev/null 2> /dev/null && echo "Node $range is up" 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Although an old question, it still seems to be important (at least important enough for me to deal with this). My script relies on nmap too, so nothing special here except that ou can define which interface you want to scan and the IP Range is created automagically (at least kind of).

This is what I came up with

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script for scanning the (local) network for other computers 

command -v nmap >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "I require nmap but it's not installed. Aborting." >&2; exit 1; }

if [ -n ""$@"" ];  then
    ip=$(/sbin/ifconfig $1 | grep 'inet '  | awk '{ print $2}' | cut -d"." -f1,2,3 )
    nmap -sP $ip.1-255
else
    echo -e "\nThis is a script for scanning the (local) network for other computers.\n"
    echo "Enter Interface as parameter like this:"
    echo -e "\t./scannetwork.sh $(ifconfig -lu | awk '{print $2}')\n"

    echo "Possible interfaces which are up are: "   
    for i in $(ifconfig -lu)
    do
        echo -e "\033[32m \t $i \033[39;49m"
    done

    echo "Interfaces which could be used but are down at the moment: "
    for i in $(ifconfig -ld)
    do
        echo -e "\033[31m \t $i \033[39;49m"
    done
    echo
fi
```

One remark: This script is created on OSX, so there might be some changes to linux environments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide a list of hosts it can be done with nmap, grep and awk.

Install nmap:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Create file hostcheck.sh like this:

hostcheck.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

nmap -sP -iL hostlist -oG pingscan > /dev/null
grep Up pingscan | awk '{print $2}' > uplist
grep Down pingscan | awk '{print $2}' > downlist
```

-sP: Ping Scan - go no further than determining if host is online

-iL : Input from list of hosts/networks

-oG : Output scan results in Grepable format, to the given filename.

/dev/null : Discards output

Change the access permission:

```
$ chmod 775 hostcheck.sh
```

Create file hostlist with the list of hosts to be checked (hostname or IP):

hostlist (Example)

```
192.168.1.1-5
192.168.1.101
192.168.1.123
```

192.168.1.1-5 is a range of IPs

Run the script:

./hostcheck.sh hostfile

Will be generated files pingscan with all the information, uplist with the hosts online (Up) and downlist with the hosts offline (Down).

uplist (Example)

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.101
```

downlist (Example)

```
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.123
```

Answer (score 1):

Some machines don't answer pings (e.g. firewalls).

If you only want the local network you can use this command:

```
(for n in $(seq 1 254);do sudo arping -c1 10.0.0.$n &  done ; wait) | grep reply | grep --color -E '([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+'
```

#### Explanations part !

1. `arping` is a command that sends ARP requests. It is present on most of linux.

Example:

```
sudo arping -c1 10.0.0.14
```

the sudo is not necessary if you are root ofc.

- `10.0.0.14` : the ip you want to test
- `-c1` : send only one request.

---

2. `&`: the 'I-don't-want-to-wait' character

This is a really useful character that give you the possibility to launch a command in a sub-process without waiting him to finish (like a thread)

---

3. the `for` loop is here to arping all 255 ip addresses. It uses the `seq` command to list all numbers.

---

4. `wait`: after we launched our requests we want to see if there are some replies. To do so we just put `wait` after the loop.
   `wait` looks like the function `join()` in other languages.

---

5. `()`: parenthesis are here to interpret all outputs as text so we can give it to `grep`

---

6. `grep`: we only want to see replies. the second grep is just here to highlight IPs.

hth

#### Edit 20150417:  Maxi Update !

The bad part of my solution is that it print all results at the end. It is because grep have a big enough buffer to put some lines inside.
the solution is to add `--line-buffered` to the first grep.
like so:

```
(for n in $(seq 1 254);do sudo arping -c1 10.0.0.$n &  done ; wait) | grep --line-buffered reply | grep --color -E '([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+'
```

Comment: I appreciate the referece to arping as an alternative and that firewalls may not respond to ping

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((n=0 ; n < 30 ; n+=1))
do
    ip=10.1.1.$n
    if ping -c 1 -w 1 $ip > /dev/null 2> /dev/null >> /etc/logping.txt; then  
        echo "${ip} is up" # output up
        # sintax >> /etc/logping.txt log with .txt format
    else
        echo "${ip} is down" # output down
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The following (evil) code runs more than TWICE as fast as the nmap method

```
for i in {1..254} ;do (ping 192.168.1.$i -c 1 -w 5  >/dev/null && echo "192.168.1.$i" &) ;done
```

takes around 10 seconds, where the standard nmap

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-254
```

takes 25 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is part of a script of mine.

> **ship.sh**  A simple, handy network addressing  multitool with plenty of features

**Pings network, displays online hosts on that network with their local IP and MAC address**

It doesn't require any edit. Needs root permission to run.

```
GOOGLE_DNS="8.8.8.8"
ONLINE_INTERFACE=$(ip route get "${GOOGLE_DNS}" | awk -F 'dev ' 'NR == 1 {split($2, a, " "); print a[1]}')
NETWORK_IP=$(ip route | awk "/${ONLINE_INTERFACE}/ && /src/ {print \$1}" | cut --fields=1 --delimiter="/")
NETWORK_IP_CIDR=$(ip route | awk "/${ONLINE_INTERFACE}/ && /src/ {print \$1}")
FILTERED_IP=$(echo "${NETWORK_IP}" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} NF--')

ip -statistics neighbour flush all &>/dev/null

echo -ne "Pinging ${NETWORK_IP_CIDR}, please wait ..."
for HOST in {1..254}; do
  ping "${FILTERED_IP}.${HOST}" -c 1 -w 10 &>/dev/null &
done

for JOB in $(jobs -p); do wait "${JOB}"; done

ip neighbour | \
    awk 'tolower($0) ~ /reachable|stale|delay|probe/{printf ("%5s\t%s\n", $1, $5)}' | \
      sort --version-sort --unique
```