# Fastest way to ping a network range and return responsive hosts?

Tags: linux, performance, bash, networking, ping

Constraints:
1. Speed matters.
2. I am allowed to ping once.

I'm debating whether to use Python or shellscripting. Is there a method faster than `bash`?

Here is the current code,

```
for ip in $(seq int1 int2); do
    ping -c 1 xxx.xxx.xxx.$ip | grep "bytes from" &
done
```

Anything faster than this?

Comment: Refer to d3v3l's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733418/how-can-i-write-a-linux-bash-script-that-tells-me-which-computer-are-on-in-my-l).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You should use `nmap`:

```
nmap -T5 -sn 192.168.0.0-255
nmap -T insane -sn 192.168.0.0-255 # same as above but w/named template
```

The `-T 5/insane` option uses the "insane" template, which:

> insane mode assumes that you are on an extraordinarily fast network or are willing to sacrifice some accuracy for speed.
> `-T4` (aggressive) prohibits the dynamic scan
> delay from exceeIf you are on a decent broadband or ethernet connection, I would recommend always using -T4. Some people love -T5 though it is too aggressive
> ding 10 ms for TCP ports and -T5 (insane) caps that value at 5 ms.
> If you are on a decent broadband or ethernet connection, I would recommend always using -T4. Some people love -T5 though it is too aggressive for my taste.

The `-sn` option means "no port scan":

> This option tells Nmap not to do a port scan after host discovery, and only print out the available hosts that responded to the host discovery
> probes. This is often known as a “ping scan”, but you can also request that traceroute and NSE host scripts be run. This is by default one step
> more intrusive than the list scan, and can often be used for the same purposes. It allows light reconnaissance of a target network without
> attracting much attention. Knowing how many hosts are up is more valuable to attackers than the list provided by list scan of every single IP
> and host name.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think about this. Would there be a fast way to do this in Python as well? Seems everything I find is almost a page long.

Comment: I see no reason you need Python for this task.

Comment: Tried this one. It's really cool 'cause nmap automatically filters hosts that are up and it gives you host type + MAC Address. Excellent. Thanks also for explaining about Python. Taking a pentest course where they suggest to use higher level languages. But the goal is speed here.

Comment: You can run nmap command from python using result=subprocess.Popen() command to run shell code from command line.

Comment: As mentioned below, you can speed up the nmap ping scan by adjusting the timeout. On a local network with low latency you can use `nmap -T5 -sP 192.168.0.0/24`. It goes from 25 sec. to 2 sec. for a /24 subnet.

Comment: The `-sP` flag (no port scan) has been renamed to `-sn`, quote from `man nmap`: _"In previous releases of Nmap, -sn was known as -sP"_

Comment: Thanks, I just updated `-sP` to `-sn`.

Answer (score 55):

The following (evil) code runs more than TWICE as fast as the nmap method

```
for i in {1..254} ;do (ping 192.168.1.$i -c 1 -w 5  >/dev/null && echo "192.168.1.$i" &) ;done
```

takes around 10 seconds, where the standard nmap

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-254
```

takes 25 seconds...

Comment: Thank you, that was answered but yes that is the best answer :)

Comment: You can adjust timeouts and nmap will be very fast.

Comment: It seems like this is sequentially trying each IP in the network one after the other in series, which seems fundamentally slow. The 5ms timeout (`-w 5`) makes it loop quickly but it's possible that a valid host on a network might take longer than that to respond, so this might lead to false negatives. You could adjust this to some higher values but that would obviously make it much slower.

Comment: No, it is actually doing 255 pings in parallel  (that's why it's evil!). The & symbol at the end means 'do in background' without waiting.

Comment: why is this not the best answer? "Roman Newaza" answer is too slow. It shouldn't even be a suggestion. At the very least make the function work like this answer so it isn't useless.

Comment: Added benefit of the evil answer ... nmap is not always installed by default.

Comment: This works extremely well and quickly.  Some networks have been banning nmap from even running on them.

Comment: Use capital w ("-W") for macos/BSD

Comment: Also, nmap is not installed on all corporate workstations where as ping usually seems to be - presumably, for support staff troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this somewhat dirty, but available everywhere solution!

Comment: This is great! However, shall You find yourself on a macos system, just drop `-w 5`

Comment: For older bash versions i needed to change the range statement and rearange the ping command to look like this: `for i in $(seq 1 254) ;do (ping -c 1 -w 5 192.168.0.$i >/dev/null && echo "192.168.0.$i" &); done`

Comment: If you need speed then remove `echo` - `for i in {1..254} ;do (ping 192.168.0.$i -c 1 >/dev/null &) ;done`

Answer (score 14):

Try this for a unique list.

`ping -c 5 -b 10.10.0.255 | grep 'bytes from' | awk '{ print $4 }' | sort | uniq`

another method (fetches live hosts):

`fping -ag 192.168.1.0/24`

Comment: Thank you Sunny. Using fping seems appealing. I will try tomorrow when I connect to the lab.

Comment: Sunny, thank you for your help :). The first command took a while to execute even though I liked the fact that you used awk. The second command was better and I like the output with -ag which was cool. However, for the test that I am doing speed is crucial. So far nothing I tried could beat nmap. So I placed a like on your answer, but I am selecting Roman's because it was the one that helped the most, speed-wise. Tks for helping.

Comment: That failed to work for me.  -w was not an option.  I did get it working this way though `for i in {1..254}; do (ping -vc 1 -t 4 192.168.1.$i); done`

Answer (score 5):

Try both of these commands and see for yourself why arp is faster:

## PING:

for ip in $(seq 1 254); do ping -c 1 10.185.0.$ip > /dev/null; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "10.185.0.$ip UP" || : ; done

## ARP:

for ip in $(seq 1 254); do arp -n 10.185.0.$ip | grep Address; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "10.185.0.$ip UP" || : ; done

Answer (score 1):

This is python code for the ping in range of the `192.168.0.0-192.168.0.100`. You can change for loop as you comfort.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket
import os
import sys

up_ip =[] #list to store the ip-addresses of server online
for x in range(100):  #here range is 0-100. You can change the range according to your comfort

    server_ip = '192.168.0.'+ str(x)
    print "Trying ,server_ip,... \n"

    rep = os.system('ping -c 1 ' + server_ip)

    if rep == 0:
        up_ip.append(server_ip)
        print '******************* Server Is Up **************** \n'
    else:
        print 'server is down \n'

print up_ip
```

Comment: Guy asked for fastest way, phyton is far from fast and far from just running by default on windows

Answer (score 1):

If time matters (and I know the feeling):

```
for i in {1..254}; do
echo -n -e "$i      \r"     
timeout --preserve-status .2  ping -c1 -q 10.0.0.$i  &> /dev/null
[ $? -eq 0 ]&&echo 10.0.0.$i is happy to serve to his master!
done # as I am
```

The command:

```
timeout --preserve-status .2  ping -c1 -q 10.0.0.107 &> /dev/null  ;echo $?
```

returns 143 with non-existing PC and 0 with existing PC and waits for the answer just and only for .2 second because TIME MATTERS! And therefore I have to look for my lost keys now.

Answer (score 1):

```
subnet="182.17.207"
fun(){
       ip="$subnet.$1"
       res=`ping -c 1 $ip | grep "1 packets transmitted, 1 received" | wc -l`
       if [ $res == 1 ]
       then
           echo "$ip => live"
       fi
}
for i in $(seq 1 254)
do
   fun $i &
   sleep 0.005
done
sleep 0.5
echo
```

Fast using linux fork, sleep is optional .. just to print in order.

Answer (score 0):

This script runs on Git Bash (MINGW64) on Windows and return a messages depending of the ping result.

```
#!/bin/bash
#$1 should be something like "19.62.55"

if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "No identify of the network supplied, i.e. 19.62.55"
else
    ipAddress=$1

    for i in {1..256} ;do 
    (
        {
        ping -w 5 $ipAddress.$i ; 
        result=$(echo $?);
        } &> /dev/null


        if [ $result = 0 ]; then
            echo Successful Ping From : $ipAddress.$i
        else
            echo Failed Ping From : $ipAddress.$i
        fi &);
    done

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

BSD's

for i in $(seq 1 254); do (ping -c1 -W5 192.168.1.$i >/dev/null && echo "192.168.1.$i" &) ;done

Comment: I doubt that this helps or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please add an explanation how this works and why it is supposed to help.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the original reply but it did not give me the sequential sequence I was looking for.

I approached this a little different and it works great:

```
for ip in {int1..int2} 
do
    ping -c 1 xxx.xxx.xxx.$ip | grep "bytes from"
done
```